# redirection error while redirecting to xyz.com

Tags: .htaccess, web

myhtaccess code contains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://xyz23465.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^52\.71\.19\.242
RewriteRule (.*) http://xyz23465.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I type `https://www.xyz23465.com` it redirects me to `http://xyz23465.com/http://www.xyz23465.com/` which becomes a url not found.

Could you please suggest?